# Making custom animation on image of on-boarding screen

Tags: flutter, dart, animation, flutter-animation, mobile-application

I want to ask you how can i create this animation on flutter for the on-Boarding Screen.

[image: image of animation]

I tried to create it animation on on-boarding screen with GetX but it's giving errors only.

Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: You can check https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/animations/tutorial

Comment: check `AnimatedCrossFade`, more https://youtu.be/PGK2UUAyE54

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.